# Thread1:exc_bad_access error - Programatic Modal View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been trying to get a Modal view to display with a transparant background - which I have managed programatically with the help of @Tommaso Resti [Modal View Transparant background - stop lower layer hiding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998359/xcode-modal-view-transparant-background-stop-lower-layer-hiding)

Prior to implementing the modal view programatically I had it connected via a segue - the modal (which has a class of shareScreenViewController) contains to buttons with ibconnections to methods in its .m file.  The methods fired without issue with teh segue connection - but now the view is added programatically when i click on a button the app crashes with the error -

```
Thread1:Exc_Bad_Access(code=1...
```

shown in the screenshot below - I have added breakpoints and it appears that the method isnt even called before the app crashes - No idea whats going on - can anyone offer any advice!?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
from @Larme 's help below I enabled NSZombie and now get this error -

2013-11-15 15:04:37.754 GetPTFit[1574:60b] Animation completed
2013-11-15 15:04:39.419 GetPTFit[1574:60b] *** -[shareScreenViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16e1f2d0
(lldb)

The code i'm using to setup the modal is as follows -

```
- (IBAction)shareBtn:(id)sender {


UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"
                                                         bundle: nil];
UIViewController *myModalController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"shareScreenViewController"];
[myModalController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview: myModalController.view]; /* UPDATED HERE! */


/* Animate it from the bottom */
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    myModalController.view.transform = move;   /* UPDATED HERE */
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished) {
        NSLog(@"Animation completed");
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: Did you set NSZombie to get what object was released before you want to access it?

Comment: nope - sorry no idea what that means - (reasonably new to IOS dev and only used storyboard in the past).  How would I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Comment: cool - makes sense - ok now I get this error - 
2013-11-15 15:04:37.754 GetPTFit[1574:60b] Animation completed
2013-11-15 15:04:39.419 GetPTFit[1574:60b] *** -[shareScreenViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16e1f2d0
(lldb)

Comment: Seems that you wanted to do performSelector:WithObject:withObject: and it got release before. So you want your shareScreenViewController to do something although it doesn't exists anymore. More code should be good to help you.

Comment: Cheers @Larme - Added above

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear. It's not really related to NSZombie. NSZombie is mostly a tool to detect this kind of error (what object was release too soon).

Comment: fair enough - edited above accordingly

Comment: just try to add myModalController as a child view controller. add [self addChildViewController: myModalController] after you add the subview.

Comment: Cheers @Danyun - That worked!  If you add an answer I'll give you a tick.  Would I have to do anything special to remove that from memory awhen closing the modal?

Comment: You need to do nothing about that if you are using arc.

Comment: cool - add your comment as an answer and i'll tick it off as its all working fine