# How to make a Method display a new ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I make a Method display a new ViewController? I am trying to make the

Currently what I have :

```
-(void)gameOver{

    [groundMovement invalidate];
    [guyMovement invalidate];

    topGround.hidden = YES;
    bottomGround.hidden = YES;
    guy.hidden = YES;
    scoreLabel.hidden = YES;


    gameViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"gameOver" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameOverViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    if (score > highScore) {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
    }        
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using storyboards in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are using storyboards in your project, first make sure that your view controllers have a storyboard identifier. You can set it through the identity inspector in xCode. Then, you can instantiate a new view controller by calling:

```
YourViewControllerClass *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerId"]; // Replace "MainStoryboard" and "ViewControllerId" with your storyboard name and the storyboard id for your view controller respectively
```

Then, depending on how your needs you can either push the new view controller (if for example you're using a navigation controller):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or present it modally

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Would I put :

`YourViewControllerClass *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];`

in the method and also include

`[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES];` @spassas

Comment: @Sephireth Yes, the first line instantiates your VC, the second presents it.

Comment: I get an error on the second line :No visible @interface for 'gameViewController' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:'

Comment: @Sephireth Sorry, my mistake. Try `[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];`. I edited the answer as well

Comment: Now when its executed in-game it crashes the app. I am not sure if I setup Storyboard IDs correctly, I have 3 VC , do I give each the same SB ID or different ones. ?

Comment: @Sephireth Make sure that your storyboard name, as well as view controller storyboard id and class are set properly. What error do you get?

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this) for understanding the storyboard IDs

Comment: @Sephireth Your identifier is `gameOver` and not `gameOverViewController`. And your storyboard name is wrong, replace it with the filename of your storyboard file without the `.storyboard` extension

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)terminate{

    MyNewViewController *myNewVC = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];

    // do any setup you need for myNewVC

    [self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have been working on this for couple hours straight, how would I setup the new VC? @Pano Katsourakis

Comment: The setup is only for passing data along to the VC if you have to.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't complete it >.< @Pano Katsourakis

Comment: Is it cool if you can help me do the setup? @Pano Katsourakis