# How to redirect to a page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I am new to IOS. I created a simple storyboard layout, something as shown below:

```
-> Navigation --> login --> Welcome screen
```

When I build and run the setup, I can see the login page with username and password textfields and a button ('login').

But I am unable to understand How I should redirect the page to welcome screen when the user has entered something inside the username and password textfields.

To achieve this, I added a controller `LoginViewController` to the login page and inside that controller's `.h` file, I added the following code:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username_text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pwd_text;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)login_btn:(id)sender {
    if([self validOrNot]){
//        UIviewcontrollerWelcom *vc = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
//        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:WelcomeViewController];
        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];

    }
}
- (BOOL)validOrNot{
    if ([self.pwd_text hasText] && [self.username_text hasText]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Please guide me how should I redirect to next page which is welcome screen when user enter something in username and password textfields of the login page.

Comment: as I can see, you are trying to present navigation controller. But i think you need to present welcome page. am i correct?

Comment: I am trying to navigate from login page to welcome page when the user enters something in username and password, and then presses "login" button.

Comment: do u have welcome page files created?

Comment: @T_77 yes I have them created and attached to the welcome view. The name of the controller is `WelcomeViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

Give the storyboard id for the welcome page view controller in the storyboard.

And you can present the welcome page view controller with the following line of code:

```
 WelcomeViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeView"];

 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For setting up the storyboard ID, see this [link :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this)

Comment: I need to do this using navigation controller. Eventhough, I tried this, I am getting two errors `use of undeclared identifier vc` and `use of undeclared identifier WelcomeView`.

Comment: WelcomeView is the storyboard id you need to give on your storyboard to your welcome view controller

Comment: you need to import the welcomeViewController.h  file

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
- (IBAction)login_btn:(id)sender {
   if([self validOrNot]){
 WelcomeViewController *wVC = [[WelcomeViewController alloc]init];

 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
[navigationController pushViewController:wVC animated:YES];


}
}
```

Comment: I am getting error, `use of undeclared identifier wVC`. I think `WelcomeViewController` is somehow unrecognizable. What should I do to make it recognizable?

Comment: Import WelcomeViewController in your LoginViewController.h file with a #import "WelcomeViewController.h"           statement

Comment: Thanks it is working.. but why it is redirecting me to welcome page when I don't enter anything in the username and password fields? It is not redirecting to welcome page when I enter something in those fields.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using??