# fatal error after reloadData UITableView in other class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode7-beta3

I'm very new to programming and have a big problem, I spent many hours to solve it. But I don't understand why this is going wrong.

I have a `ViewController` with a `TableView` and a another `ViewController` wheres a View you can add data to the `TableView`. From this class I call a func from the first `ViewController` class, in this func is the `reloadData`. And here starts the problem. The app stops, and this only when I call the func in the second class. When I call it in the first class never a problem appears.

Here is the first class:

```
class GebieteViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Here is the func:

```
func ladeDaten(){

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Territory")
    do {
        territorys = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Territory]
    } catch let gebieteError as NSError {
        print("error: \(gebieteError.localizedDescription)")
    }
    gebieteTableView.reloadData()

}
```

Here is the second class:

```
class NewGebietViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate{
```

Here is the func:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let neuesGebiet = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Territory", inManagedObjectContext: self.targetVC.context) as! Territory
    neuesGebiet.territoryName = self.newGebietNameTextField.text
    do {
    try self.targetVC.context.save()
    }catch let gebieteError as NSError {
        print("error: \(gebieteError.localizedDescription)")
    }
    self.targetVC.ladeDaten()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    return true
}
```

A picture that shows the error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUo3e.png

Thank you for your help.

More code from the first class:

```
class GebieteViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBOutlet weak var gebieteTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var newGebietButton: DesignableButton!
var territorys: [Territory]!
```

More code from the second class:

```
class NewGebietViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var newGebietNameTextField: UITextField!

let targetVC = GebieteViewController()
```

Comment: The `gebieteTableView` is a nil. Are you using storyboard? Post your code about the initialization of the `GebieteViewController`.

Comment: @Bannings do you mean the initialization in the `NewGebietViewController`?

Comment: Yeah, I think that maybe your initialization is incorrect. Again, are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes i use Storyboard, but i made my own TableViewController. I put a TableView into a ViewController, i also set the delegate and DataSource. I must do this while i want a button over the TableView.

Comment: OK, how did you initialize the `GebieteViewController` in the `NewGebietViewController`?

Comment: in the new lines of code you can see i named it `targetVC`. It´s the last line in my question.

Comment: Check my answer. Let me know if that works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this line:

```
let targetVC = GebieteViewController()
```

with:

```
lazy var targetVC: GebieteViewController = {
    let targetVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourIdentifier") as! GebieteViewController
    return targetVC
}()
```

Using the storyboard id you set in interface builder to create and return the view controller.

> **Where can I find the name of my "Identifier"?**

See also:

- http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html
- [What is a StoryBoard ID and how can i use this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this)

---

**UPDATED:**(after seeing the project)

The problem is that you initialized the `GebieteViewController` but you did not display it so the `tableView` is nil. That means the `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` will not be execute in the `targetVC`.

BTW, you don't need to create a new `GebieteViewController` because the `NewGebietViewController` was presented via Modally, so just get it, then you can call the `reloadData` of the existed `GebieteViewController` instance.

To fix this just use these code:

```
lazy var targetVC: GebieteViewController = {
    let targetVC = (self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! GebieteViewController
    return targetVC
}()
```

Comment: Where can i find the name of my "Identifier"?

Comment: The link will helps you:http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html

Comment: Ok i understand what the Storyboard ID is. Now Xcode says "NewGebieteViewController does not have a member named ´storyboard´"

Comment: Updated my answer again. You should use the `lazy loading`.

Comment: Yeah it's the same error as before. I don't understand why. Your answer looks so right...

Comment: If possible, you can send me your implement. I shall fix it :)

Comment: Oh what were fantastic, but how can i do this?

Comment: @DanK7 You can share your project on Dropbox or send to my Gmail:zhangao0086@gmail.com

Comment: I sent you an email :)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I can´t tell you how happy i am now :D. When i have in the future some trouble and post it on stack overflow, can i send you a link? You are my hero ;)

Comment: @DanK7 My pleasure :)