# UIPageviewcontroller from the middle of iOS App swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I found a nice [VIdeo Tutorial](https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/4/2/uipageviewcontroller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial) for UIPageViewController in swift, and it's working nice. In my app, i'm trying to create a pageviewcontroller from the middle of the app, not from the beginning. I couldn't find the storyboard ID for the pageviewcontroller and viewcontroller, which is essential in the coding. How can I solve this?

[image: Identity inspector]

Comment: I have updated the question. This is the identity inspector of the xib i prefer to start the pageviewcontroller

Comment: It's hard to understand but if your asking what i think then take look at this on how to load a standalone viewcontroller from a storyboard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this

Comment: I understand, it's almost what i'm asking. But how can I confirm a storyboard declared in AppDelegate and and a viewcontroller created somewhere in the app is connected?

Comment: That question refers to instantiate a viewcontroller with a specific storyboard id. My problem is, I am unable to set the storyboard id from a new xib other than the Main.Storyboard

Comment: So you have a MyViewController.xib, you have to init it with                  [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]; then present it or push it on to the navigation controller. Swift: init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil))

Comment: @BooRanger Could you elaborate it. Where i have to initialise, and how it can be completed. Please write it as an answer.

Comment: I am creating a page view. So, i've to set storyboard id for another viewcontroller and pageviewcontroller.