# Cannot convert the type 'int' to expected type NSTimeInterval in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this method in Objective-C  to return the time stamp of the location sent to the server.

```
-(NSDate *) toLocalTime
{
   NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
   NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: [NSDate date]];
   return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: [NSDate date]];
}
```

This works perfectly in Obj-C
I have converted it to swift 2.0

```
func toLocalTime() -> NSDate {
    var tz : NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    var seconds: Int = tz.secondsFromGMTForDate(NSDate())
    return (NSDate(timeInterval: seconds, sinceDate: NSDate()))
}
```

but when I convert this to swift 2.0 , error(mentioned as the title above) is shown for this line as the variable seconds is of type Int and the variable that should be passed to dateWithTimeInterval should be NSTimeInterval.

> Error:Cannot convert the type 'int' to expected type NSTimeInterval

`Error line: return (NSDate(timeInterval: seconds, sinceDate: NSDate()))`

please help !

Comment: can you not just go `var seconds: NSTimeInterval = tz.secondsFromGMTForDate(NSDate())` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check Date class .. you can found `public typealias NSTimeInterval = Double` means return type is Double for NSTimeInterval ..

and the method is

```
public convenience init(timeInterval secsToBeAdded: NSTimeInterval, sinceDate date: NSDate)  
// timeInterval -> return NSTimeInterval 
// date          -> return NSDate
```

timeInterval takes `Double` not `int` ... so just convert it to Double like

```
 func toLocalTime() -> NSDate {
    let tz  = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    let seconds = tz.secondsFromGMTForDate(NSDate())
    return (NSDate(timeInterval: Double(seconds), sinceDate: NSDate()))
 }
```

Comment: can u help me with this question as well @El Captain..?                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078975/cannot-convert-value-of-type-uint-to-expected-argument-type-unsafemutablepoin

Comment: ohk ... I think you got your solution .. :)

Comment: @El Captain , can you please help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194577/not-able-to-set-nsuserdefaults

Comment: I would have added important information in comments*

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code:

```
func toLocalTime() -> NSDate {
    let tz : NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    let seconds: Int = tz.secondsFromGMTForDate(NSDate())
    return (NSDate(timeInterval: Double(seconds), sinceDate: NSDate()))
}
```

You need to convert to `Double`

Comment: Thank you Sohil. I have another Doubt in my code , but not in this part. Can I ask it here or Should I post another question ?

Comment: @ManeeshSharma You can go here!

Comment: I have a HomeViewController : UITableViewController and three other controllers namely DetailsViewController : UITableViewController and

Comment: AppcatalogViewController: UIViewController. In didSelectRowAtindexpath of homecontroller, i am loading the otherControllers using   if (indexPath.section == 0){
            var enrolledView = DetailsViewController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(enrolledView, animated: true)
        }

Comment: but when i load AppCatalogcontroller, which is inherited from UIViewController, error is shown as "Use of Unresolved Identifier 'AppCatalogViewController'". Please help with how should I load it

Comment: @ManeeshSharma Can I see that code of how you load `AppCatalogViewController`?

Comment: if (indexPath.section == 1){
            var appcatalog = AppCatalogViewController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(appcatalog, animated: true)
        }

Comment: @ManeeshSharma You are doing it in a wrong way. You are creating a wrong instance. Refer to this answer: `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as MyCustomViewController
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this

Comment: I Haven't used a StoryBoard in my Project Sohil

Answer (score 0):

Cast seconds:Int into Double

```
func toLocalTime() -> NSDate {
    var tz : NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    var seconds: Int = tz.secondsFromGMTForDate(NSDate())
    return (NSDate(timeInterval: Double(seconds), sinceDate: NSDate()))
}
```