# Cannot convert value of type 'UInt' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to initialize a String from the content accessible by a URL:

```
actualresponse.response = String(contentsOfURL: url, usedEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

I get the following error thrown, pointing at the usedEncoding:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UInt' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

Can anyone tell me why this error is thrown and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two similar but different methods which can be mistaken.

- The usual method is

  ```
  init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL,
      encoding enc: UInt) throws
  ```

  The `encoding` parameter takes an `NSStringEncoding` value to specify the encoding, for example

  ```
  let string = try? String(contentsOfURL:url, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  ```

---

- The second method **retrieves** the encoding from the file by passing a pointer as `usedEncoding` parameter

  ```
  init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL,
      usedEncoding enc: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>) throws
  ```

  The documentation says:

  > Upon return, if url is read successfully, contains the encoding used
  >   to interpret the data.

  That means you have to pass a pointer which will contain the determined encoding of the file.

  ```
  var encoding : NSStringEncoding = 0
  let string = try? String(contentsOfURL:url, usedEncoding:&encoding)
  ```

Comment: Thank you. Understood it Clearly @vadian.