# How to pass an Int value to an Objective C function from Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to pass an integer value from Swift to Objective C function where I can process it .

Objective C function definition is

```
 (void)getAllDevices:(NSInteger *)limit :(NSInteger *)offset
```

The Objective C function is part of an SDK called DemoSDK.

I try to pass the value from Swift using this function call

I tried doing doing this

```
DemoSDK.getAllDevices(10,10)
```

But the error that comes is

> cannot convert a value of type Int to expected argument of type UnsafeMutablePointer

I am very new to Objective C and this is definitely an amateur question. 
I want to send an int value to objective C function where I can process the int value. How can I do it? Please help.

Comment: You're not passing an `NSInteger`, you're passing an `NSInteger *`. Without seeing more code, I can't give you a lot of help, but you could try doing something like (in one line, sorry) `var limit = 10; var offset = 10; withUnsafePointer(to: &limit) { limit in withUnsafePointer(to: &offset) { offset in DemoSDK.getAllDevices(limit, offset) } }`

Comment: NSInteger is not a pointer type for from method call remove * front of the NSInteger and then try.

Comment: you can try [cannot convert a value of type Int to expected argument of type UnsafeMutablePointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36079331/3483725)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters aren't asking for integers, they're asking for references to integers. This is achieved with `&` in Swift.

```
var limit = Int()
var offset = Int()

DemoSDK.getAllDevices(&limit, &offset)
```

Comment: Nitpick - In the Objective-C code it's asking for pointers to integers, not references.

Answer (score 0):

There are two similar but different methods which can be mistaken.

- The usual method is

  ```
  init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL,
      encoding enc: UInt) throws
  ```

  The `encoding` parameter takes an `NSStringEncoding` value to specify the encoding, for example

  ```
  let string = try? String(contentsOfURL:url, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  ```

---

- The second method **retrieves** the encoding from the file by passing a pointer as `usedEncoding` parameter

  ```
  init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL,
      usedEncoding enc: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>) throws
  ```

  The documentation says:

  > Upon return, if url is read successfully, contains the encoding used
  >   to interpret the data.

  That means you have to pass a pointer which will contain the determined encoding of the file.

  ```
  var encoding : NSStringEncoding = 0
  let string = try? String(contentsOfURL:url, usedEncoding:&encoding)
  ```