# Encoding problems while reading files

Tags: swift, character-encoding

To read a file into a string, I'm using the following:

```
let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
```

I'm not specifying a particular encoding because, of course, the user could open any file with any encoding. Problem is, this works for some encodings and not others. Using `file -I *` in my directory or files, I realised that the files I'm trying this on are a mixture of `us-ascii` and `iso-8859-1` files. When it attempts to read `us-ascii` files, it works, but it doesn't for `iso-8859-1`.

I suppose `iso-8859-1` is less common or something, because Swift doesn't seem to be able to infer its encoding for me. Is there some way to make this work? Maybe using a library to detect encoding?

Comment: There is a method which tries to *detect* the encoding, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36079331/1187415 for an example, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31442691/1187415 (which is Objective-C, but easily translated).

Comment: That doesn't seem to help - for every file I try it says it's "Unicode (UTF-8)", but the same ones still throw an error saying "couldn't be opened because the text encoding of its contents can't be determined"

Comment: If everything else fails, try several encodings, until one succeeds.