# Not able to set NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I have built an app that is used to manage the devices. And I set the details like server name , server port , UDID , ErID, and Language_pack_enabled at the time when the app launches using NSUserDefaults. But when I try to run the app , it crashes stating that it's a bad instruction and when I debugged it , the user defaults were set to nil . Can anyone tell me how to set the server name , port and ErID to the device which is there in the profile in the device as

> (settings -> general -> device Management -> view details).

Here's my code as follows

```
let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let dict : AnyObject = userDefaults.objectForKey(mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION)!

    let serverName = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERNAMEKEY] as! NSString?
    let serverPort = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERPORTKEY] as! NSString?
    let UDID = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY] as! NSString?
    let languagePack = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.IS_LANG_PACK_ENABLED] as! NSString?
    let ErID = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.ERIDKEY] as! NSString?
```

Comment: sorry for the typographical errors though .

Comment: Please share the code where you are setting the values in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: if serverName != nil && serverPort != nil && UDID != nil {
                persist.setObject(UDID!, forKey: "\(mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY)")
                persist.setObject(serverName!, forKey: "\(mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERNAMEKEY)")
                persist.setObject(serverPort!, forKey: "\(mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERPORTKEY)")
                persist.setObject(ErID!, forKey: "\(mdmiosagent_Constants.ERIDKEY)")

Comment: if you have defined the constants then why you have put them in quotes while setting the object in user defaults/

Comment: also you are fetching the value with the key 'mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION' and you have not set any value using this key in userdefaults??

Comment: @El Captain , do u mean mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION ? if yes , it has "com.apple.configuration.managed"

Comment: Basically all these variables (serverName , serverPort, ...) are being pushed from the install profile pList.. and the key to access them is "com.apple.configuration.managed" which is set to the constant MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION.

Comment: @ManeeshSharma no I mean when you store data in defaults ... that time you check that its not nil

Comment: yes @ElCaptain , I did check and the dict that is storing the values stays nil throughout.

Comment: YES ! and the values are present there in the manifest.plist but i don't know how to access those details from the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107503/discussion-between-ei-captain-and-maneesh-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

As per your format of the data, I would suggest to create a dictionary with all your data an then please try the following:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dict, forKey: mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION)
```

check if you are able to set the value in userDefaults for the key `mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION`

Comment: I checked it with an if let statement , and i am not able to set the value in user defaults for the key 'mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION'

Comment: Basically all these variables (serverName , serverPort, ...) are being pushed from the install profile pList.. and the key to access them is "com.apple.configuration.managed" which is set to the constant MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION. So can Anyone please tell me how to access data from that plist and set it to the variables here ?

Answer (score 0):

For storing the value in the dictionary you have to check for nil and replace with `""(some default value)` before setting the dictionary as dictionary don't allow nil values for any key so dictionary is not set in userdefaults if any of the key is blank in the dictionary

You can set the all the value with some default value like "" or something like that, store that in the NSUserDefaults, after this when you get real value update the values in the NSUserDefaults, by this you will have at least some value and it will not be treated at nil

Like this:

```
let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefault.setObject("", forKey:mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY)
userDefault.setObject("", forKey: mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERNAMEKEY) 
userDefault.setObject("", forKey: mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERPORTKEY) 
userDefault.setObject("", forKey:mdmiosagent_Constants.ERIDKEY)
userDefault.setObject("", forKey:mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION)
userDefault.synchronize()
```

Then you can update with the same code when you get real value

At the time of retrieval you can check if there content in the userdefault or is it blank

Like this if your value is string in the UDIDKEY

```
let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefault.synchronize()
ket strUdid = userDefault.objectForKey(mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY)

if (strUdid.characters.count > 0) {
//get the value
}
```

// Or 2nd way

```
if (strUdid != "") {
//get the value
}
```

if your object can be anyobject you can check for the 2nd option or the nil check inside the object for any particular key

As Ujjwal has said you are not setting the value of `mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION` in the code and at the retrieval you are fetching the data from the key so it found nil at startup
So either you can all the keys as individual as you have written in the comment or set the value in the particular key instead of storing in individual keys

Comment: Basically all these variables (serverName , serverPort, ...) are being pushed from the install profile pList.. and the key to access them is "com.apple.configuration.managed" which is set to the constant MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION. So can Anyone please tell me how to access data from that plist and set it to the variables here ?