# Swift create 'universal' segue in tab bar app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a swift newbie and I've got a simple question which I hope someone can help me figure out.

I have a multi-tab app. I created some segues from the tab view controllers on the Stopryboard. I've given the segues identifiers and I'm calling them from my Tab1ViewController code using `performSegueWithIdentifier("tab1ToMyTarget", sender: sender)` no problem.

However, I'd like to be able to call the segue from any of the app's tabs without creating new segues from the other tabs' view controllers (i.e. I don't want to create `"tab2ToMyTarget"` - I presume there's a better way!).

**My question**: Do I create these 'universal' segues on the tab bar view controller (e.g. `"tabBarToTarget"`) (and if so how do I call it from one of my tab view controllers)? ...or...

Do I keep the segue from a single tab view controller (`tab1ToTarget`) and call that segue from a sibling tab view controller somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the view controller that you want to go to's [storyboard Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this). Then run this:

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController")
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank for this idea - sounds perfect and I wasn't aware of this method so thanks for taking the time to post the snippet. Will give it a try now :-)

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted - the only thing I had to do was unwrap the storyboard `let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testView")` (I still don't know when something's going to be an optional or not!...I'm such a n00b! :-)

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot about that. I will edit my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same segue to open a controller from a different one. It's better to instantiate a view controller with its storyboard id and then present/show based on the flow.