# iOS autolayout button not showing

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift3

I have used ObjC, and xib for years, now moving to Swift/Autolayout, I got a very stupid mistake, I have a hello world app with a button, Autolayout is set to show button on the middle of the screen X n Y

[image]

When I try "View as:" it shows in the middle for all screens iPhone 7p, 7, SE, 4S... it shows the button in the middle. But the button is not showing on my modal ViewController

Here how I show it,

```
@IBAction func buttonPresse(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let modalViewController = Modal1ViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And this to color background on shown modal

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.isOpaque = false
}
```

Thats all!, why is my button not showing :/ thx!

Comment: Check if button title is not set to blank string

Comment: hi @RohitKP, no it have a title,just changed the string to other value, but as you can see in screenshot it has a title, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you are present the new empty instance using `Modal1ViewController()` instead of that you need to create instance from storyboard using `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`. So try like this.

```
let modalViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Modal1ViewController") as! Modal1ViewController
modalViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(modalViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Note:** For this you need to set `Storyboard ID` with your `Modal1ViewController`, if you doesn't know how to set `Storyboard ID` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this), set the identifier like this question does.

Answer (score 1):

When we create a UI using auto-layout then we need to initialize it with the storyboard because storyboard holds the layouts and framing for subviews so If we initialize it without the reference of storyboard or Xib, only instance were created and layout is not set by own self.

**Objective-C :-**

```
Modal1ViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```

**Swift :-**

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier") as! Modal1ViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to perform any extra task on button click of previous screen, then you can directly use segue to redirect to screen and then set Presentation property of your UIViewController to Over Current Context from attribute inspector. So you don't have to do all this stuff.

`Drag mouse pointer with right click pressed or press control key and drag mouse left key from button to second screen`

[image: Give segue from button to second screen]

`Then select Show option`

[image: Select Show from popup to assign segue]

`Then open Attribute Inspector and change as shown below`

[image: UIVIewController Attribute Inspector]