# iOS : getting crash while choosing that see pageviewcontroller for first time that apps loaded

Tags: ios, swift

hi I followed some tutorial in stack for only seeing `UIPageviewcontroller` running at first time I find the best one and than implement it in app delegate .... first of all I have only one storyboard with two `viewcontroller` which first one is my `PageViewController` and second one is my `Loginvc` 
I implemented this code on appdelegate and I get crash everything looks good but I get crash this is the code that I have implement it

```
var window: UIWindow?
var story : UIStoryboard?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let lunchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "lunchedBefore")

    if lunchedBefore {
        story = UIStoryboard(name: "TShopUI", bundle: nil)
        let rootcontroller = story?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootcontroller
        }
    } else {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "lunchedBefore")
        story = UIStoryboard(name: "TShopUI", bundle: nil)
        let rootcontroller = story?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")

        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootcontroller
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

thanks for every help 
please answer as clear as you can I'm new to iOS development

Comment: It crashes only the first time right?

Comment: yes the first time that I run app it crashes thanks for helping

Comment: Please explain more. What is the crash error log.

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.  THIS MAIN ONE [UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] and this one

Comment: Hope you have already added storyboard identifier.

Comment: sorry story board identifier means name on UIstoryboard

Comment: Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this   Please note that identifier must be same in code as well as in Storyboard

Comment: it is objective-c sir do you have swift version??

Comment: the storyboard means that storyboardID in view controllers property

Comment: set storyboard name in target "main interface"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because of `UserDefaults`, you have to handle `UserDefaults` like below,

**Updated:** instead of `Bool` we can use `object`. So Whether the `if condition` satisfies, it's not a first launch. `else` it's first launch.

```
var window: UIWindow?
var story : UIStoryboard?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    if let lunchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lunchedBefore") {
        story = UIStoryboard(name: "TShopUI", bundle: nil)
        let rootcontroller = story?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootcontroller
        }
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "lunchedBefore")
        story = UIStoryboard(name: "TShopUI", bundle: nil)
        let rootcontroller = story?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootcontroller
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but it will give me this error     Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'

Comment: add the answer that I added you answer is true but it should add storyboard id

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I should set a storyboard ID for each view controller and than in delegate set their identifier