# How to control multiple navigation controller in an iOS project

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uinavigationcontroller

The structure of my project is as follows.

[image]

Initially when the user is registering or trying to login the initial navigation controller should work and after successfully registering / loggin in the user should be taken to first tab of tab bar controller. But the issue that i am facing is that i am getting 2 navigation bars in the tab bar view. Can someone guide me how to implement this in the correct way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, after the user login, do you the tabbar to be always the first controller?

Comment: @AhmadF yes thats what i want

Comment: Are you aware of how to set an identifier for the view controller in storyboard? Btw, is there any code you tired so far? if there is, don't hesitate to mention it :)

Comment: Yes. I know how to set an identifier for view controller

Comment: Added my answer. Please don't forget to accept it if provide the right solution for your case :)

Answer (score 1):

At some point, I would assume that the app is able to determine whether the user loggedin or not, based on that you have to set the desired *root view controller* for the app.

For such a case, the best place to do that is [`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) method in the AppDelegate file:

> Tells the delegate that the launch process is almost done and **the app**
>   **is almost ready to run**.

For simplicity, let's say that you are saving `isLoggedin` boolean in the UserDefault, so it could be achieved like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // the flag for determining whether the user loggedin or not
    let isLoggedin = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "K_isLoggedin")

    // the desired initial view controller (based on the value of `isLoggedin`)
    let initialViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: isLoggedin ? "TabbarIdentifier" : "FirstNavigationIdentifier")

    // setting the app rootViewController
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    return true
}
```

Note that "TabbarIdentifier" represents the tabbar controller at the storyboard and also "FirstNavigationIdentifier" represents the first navigation view controller at the storyboard.

<sub>if you are unaware of how to set the view controller identifier, checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743903/5501940) should help.</sub>

Technically speaking, setting the desired root view controller means setting the [`rootViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621581-rootviewcontroller) to the main [window](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow) of the app (AppDelegate window).

Answer (score 0):

Make one of the two navigation controllers from tabbar to initial viewcontroller and add the following in Appdelegate's didFinishLAunching

```
    if (isDashboardVC == nil || isDashboardVC == false)

         {
           let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let navigationController:UINavigationController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationmain") as! UINavigationController
           self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
           self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
           self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
         }
     else
         {

            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let tabBarIntial : UITabBarController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tabbarcontroller") as! UITabBarController

            let navigationController2:UINavigationController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerName") as! UINavigationController
            let navigationController:UINavigationController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerName") as! UINavigationController
            let navigationController3:UINavigationController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerName") as! UINavigationController
            tabBarIntial.viewControllers = [navigationController2, navigationController, navigationController3]
            tabBarIntial.selectedIndex = 1
         }
```

Comment: Did u try this ? @Jobins John