# Is it possible to present an UINavigationController from another UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have an UINavigationController which holds an UIViewController. The UIViewController acts like a menu. So I want to present an UITabBarController, by clicking on a button in my UIViewController.
However inside my UITabBarController I need for each ViewController an own UINavigationController itself. By doing something like this:
`viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVc()), ...]`

for my UITabBarController, I end up having a strange navigationBar at the top of my TableView (which is inside of my ViewController, which is presented by my TabBarController) + some warnings in the Xcode console: `new observer <UINavigationController: 0x7fd87d846a00>, removing old observer <UINavigationController: 0x7fd87f02ba00>`
The navigationBar looks like this:
[image]
So the problem is, that I add an UINavigationController inside another UINavigationController (if I remove the second UINavigationController everything works as expected). Unfortunately I need for each (Table)ViewController inside my TabBarController an own UINavigationController, because in the first (Table)ViewController I'm going to attach an UISearchController and if I would attach this UISearchController to the NavigationController which holds my TabBar, then each ViewController inside the TabBar would get this SearchController.
How could I solve this problem?
Every help is appreciated!

Comment: show us what you 've tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I believe no matter what you do, there should be only one `UINavigationController` per Navigation stack. If you use more, then it will mess up your navigation bar titles and navigation links.

You can start with a `UITabBarController` and then have one `UINavigationController` per Tab item.

Try this solution: [How to control multiple navigation controller in an iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913847/how-to-control-multiple-navigation-controller-in-an-ios-project)
.